# How to formulate Index - Match to include conditions in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to formulate an Index - Match function with three conditions:
Condition 1: It should check for only the highlighted cells
Condition 2: It should check for the same person in Scheduled Off Column
Condition 3: It should not repeat the same person again

I have two worksheets. On Sheet 1 I have the table with Positions against Employee. On Sheet2 I have the table where the Index match will be applicable. It also contains the Highlighted cells and drop down menu.
The Code should select name from the drop down list and not override the list
I have set Named Ranges in both the sheets. What I have tried is the following code.

```
Option Explicit
'use a constant to store the highlight color...
Const HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 9894500 'RGB(100, 250, 150)'Is a cell highlighted? 
EDIT: changed the function name to IsHighlighted
Function IsHighlighted(c As range)
    IsHighlighted = (c.Interior.Color = HIGHLIGHT_COLOR)
End Function

Sub AssignBided()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim cel1 As range
Dim cel2 As range
Dim Bid As range
Dim line As range
Dim Offemp As range
Dim BidL8 As range
Dim BidL8E As range
Dim coresVal As String

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set Bid = ws2.range("Bid")
Set line = ws2.range("All_Pos_Hilight_Mon")
Set Offemp = ws2.range("Off_Mon") 'Scheduled Off Column
Set BidL8 = ws1.range("Bid_Pos") 'Bided Position
Set BidL8E = ws1.range("Bid_Emp") 'Bided Employee for a Position

For Each cel1 In BidL8E
    For Each cel2 In line
        If IsHighlighted(cel2) Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Offemp, cel1.Value) > 0 Then
                coresVal = Evaluate("Index(" & BidL8E.Address & "),MATCH(" & cel2.Validation & "," & BidL8.Address & ",0))")
                Debug.Print coresVal
                cel2.Offset(0, 2).Value = coresVal
            End If
        End If
    Next cel2
Next cel1
End Sub
```

This code is not executing. I am getting the error:
    Object doesn't support this property or method
It highlights line 33. If any one can help me in this it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `Index(BidL8E.Address),MATCH` should be `Index(" & BidL8E.Address & ",MATCH`

Comment: You're not the [Dragon Reborn](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Lews_Therin_Telamon) are you?  Just that @RandAlthor might have a thing to say about that.  Sorry... bit off topic there.

Comment: Does Countif ever return a value < 0 ?  That would be new...

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for pointing that out. I corrected it.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I dont know, I am having these visions which tell me to go to Toman Head, and a horn of some sort, which I dont know if they exist. :P

Comment: @ScottCraner After correcting the code it is giving me an Object doesn't support this property error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your INDEX function is still incorrect.  Try `Debug.Print` to output it to the Immediate pane, then paste it into the cell manually and see what Excel complains about.

Comment: @TimWilliams So I found out what the problem was. The sheet in which I want the output has code: `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)`
This is why the `Index-Match` is not working. I will post a new question for this.